# likes tags don't appear in Employer view

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

Hi,

When I look at the employer view of my CV, the tags I've added to likes don't appear (but the favorites and dislikes do appear). The likes tags do appear when I select the public view, is this a bug or by design?

Comment: I'm also curious how it effects search terms.

Answer (score 1):

The search result only includes likes and dislikes -- it is a summary, so this is intentional. Not everything fits.

(it is used in searches even though it is not shown in search results)

The employer view of your CV includes everything, as does the public view -- if you make that part visible.